# Как сортировать по возрастанию и убыванию в Isotope?

Tags: jquery

Суть проблемы такова: есть список с товарами. Необходимо добавить скрипт для сортировки товаров по возрастанию и убыванию цены на них.
Используется [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/)
Цена товара заключена в классе `price`

```js
<script>
var $grid = $('.products').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.product',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    getSortData: {
        price: '.price parseFloat'
    }
});
$('.button-group').each(function(i, buttonGroup) {
    var $buttonGroup = $(buttonGroup);
    $buttonGroup.on('click', 'button', function() {
        $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
        $(this).addClass('is-checked');
    });
});
$('.sort-by-button-group').on('click', 'button', '.ask', function() {
    $grid.isotope({
        sortBy: 'price',
        sortAscending: true
    });
});
$('.sort-by-button-group').on('click', 'button', '.desc', function() {
    $grid.isotope({
        sortBy: 'price',
        sortAscending: false
    });
});

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3.0.4/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-group sort-by-button-group" id="sorts" style="display: inline-block">
  <button class="less" style="border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px; background-color: #8EB2C5">
<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>LESS</button>
  <button class="more is-checked" style="border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0; background-color: #8EB2C5">
<i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>MORE</button></div>
```

Необходимо, чтобы после нажатия на кнопки, их можно было нажимать еще не раз.
Как этого добиться? Мой код работает некорректно, к сожалению

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено.

```js
var $grid = $('.products').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.product',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  getSortData: {
    price: '.price parseFloat'
  }
});
$('.sort-by-button-group').on('click', 'a', function() {
  var sortValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-value');
  var sortDirection = $(this).attr('data-sort-direction');
  sortDirection = sortDirection == 'asc';
  $grid.isotope({
    sortBy: sortValue,
    sortAscending: sortDirection
  });
});

// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each(function(i, buttonGroup) {
  var $buttonGroup = $(buttonGroup);
  $buttonGroup.on('click', 'button', function() {
    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
    $(this).addClass('is-checked');
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="button-group btn-group sort-by-button-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Сортировка <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a data-sort-value="price" data-sort-direction="asc" class="is-checked">по повышению цены</a></li>
    <li><a data-sort-value="price" data-sort-direction="desc">по понижению цены</a></li>
    <li><a>по новинкам</a></li>
    <li><a>по скидкам</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```